# Deactivate icloud

Tags: icloud

I have damaged my screen and to get a new iPhone on my insurance I have to deactivate my iCloud account. Can I still receive calls on my iPhone without the I cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - just start making calls with the new device. Once you get to a computer, you can log in to iCloud and remove the activation lock on that device if you want to clear up that. If the device is dead, there's no harm in leaving it locked forevermore afaik.

Here's how to remove activation lock if the device is dead:

- https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/

If the serial number is locked, there are instructions at the bottom of that page on how to proceed. One method is to sign out on the device itself, the other is to sign in to iCloud.com on any computer and release the lock.

Comment: My bet is the insurance company will want it unlocked so they can fix it, wipe it & sell it on. Otherwise they have a paperweight.

Comment: @Tetsujin is correct, many insurance providers won't even ship the new phone until you switch off findmyiphone or log into you iCloud account and remove the old device.  The OP might be asking if he can continue to receive calls on the old device until the new one arrives.  The answer is yes, the phone doesn't need to be logged in to receive calls, having the sim in the phone is all that's needed to receive calls.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I've added that notice explicitly on how to remove the lock.